# Custom Retry Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

Trying to create a function `retry` that returns a function that calls and returns value from callback function passing its arguments and catches errors. If error is caught it should return the callback function with catch. If number of errors exceeds count then throw an Error.

Here is what was done so far:

```
const retry = (count, callback) => {
    let attempts = 1;
    const _retry = async (...args) => callback(...args)
        .catch(err => {
            if (attempts > count) throw err
            attempts++
            return _retry(...args)
        });
    return _retry
}
```

The [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSbiH.png) appears when called:

```
var r = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
var arg = (n) => async (...v) =>
    --n < 0 ? v : Promise.reject(Error(`>>> x:${v}`))
    
await retry(3, arg(2))(r)
```

Comment: I think you are calling the function while passing it as a parameter -> arg(2)

Comment: What's `_retry`. It doesn't appear to be declared...

Comment: not really, there is another arg: async (...v)

Comment: @AluanHaddad It could be const _retry and the return _retry

Comment: Right, but if it's not, you are mutating an implicit global variable in an asynchronous context, that's a disaster. You must declare it or make it a named function expression instead of an arrow function, that would work as well.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you for notice thought, I missed the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like retry returns a Promise right now, due to the async keyword. Try dropping the async keyword from the retry definition and make the _retry function async:

```
const retry = (count, callback) => {
    let attempts = 1;
    return _retry = async (...args) => callback(...args)
        .catch(err => {
            if (attempts > count) throw err
            attempts++
            return _retry(...args)
        });
}
```